# How to get dynamic form value after click submit in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, for-loop, submit

I have a dynamic form data which is loaded from backend. If there are static form, I can get value by document.getElementById("xxx"). However, if there are dynamic form which is unknown  id, how can I get the value ? I would like to have these format to submit on it

```
    "answers" :[
    {
        "questionId" : 1002,
        "response" : "Yes"
    },{
        "questionId" : 1001,
        "response" : "No"
    }
]
```

[Here is stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-wgiwjw?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put your form fields inside a `form` tag (including the submit
   button).
2. Give a class to the form e.g. `custom-form`
3. Add a submit listener on the `.custom-form` selector.

   ```
   $('.custom-form').on('submit', function formSubmitHandler(event) {  
       // add logic here 
   });
   ```
4. Inside the submit handler, get the input fields by doing something
   like this:

   ```
   const formInputs = $(this).find("input");  //this will retrieve all the input tags inside the form.
   ```

   You can now loop through them and
   perform your desired operation.

Answer (score 0):

When you are looping over the form, you can generate class name or id from data fetched from backend, or you can construct new one.